# Disabled button Angular2

Tags: angular

I want disabled button in Angular when my user does click in save ->

HTML ->

```
 <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">

 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="myForm.form.pristine">Save</button>
```

.ts

```
 save(myForm: NgForm) {
    myForm.form.pristine;
}
```

Then if my User does change in my form I need activated my button.

```
Error->
{
    "message": "unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: `myForm.form.pristine;` is your problem as the error clearly states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you mean by `[disabled]="myForm.form.pristine"` ? `@Input() disabled: boolean //Whether the component is disabled.`

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">

 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="isDisbled">Save</button>
```